# jquery delay function with IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can anyone tell me why my IF statement is firing before updating the UI with the each loop?

The code basically wants to delay adding css classes to the UI then once each one has been added, redirect the user. It currently just directs immediately?!

```
$("#logo").click(function() {

    //define variables:
    var eventDuration = 500;
    var elementArray = ['ribbon', 'left-panel', 'wid-id-1', 'wid-id-2'];
    var animationArray = ['slideOutRight', 'slideOutLeft', 'rotateOutUpRight', 'rotateOutUpRight'];

    //Loop through elements and update UI with timer function:
    $.each(elementArray, function(index, value) {

        //Increments the delay of the element updates:
        var delaytimer = index * eventDuration + eventDuration;

        //Adds animation css classes to onpage elements:
        $('#' + value).delay(delaytimer).queue(function() {
            $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationArray[index]).dequeue();
        });

        //Once complete redirect to the home page:
        if (index === 3) {
            $(this).delay(delaytimer + 500).queue(function() {
                window.location.replace('/').dequeue;
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Also any critism of the jquery above is welcome. Pretty sure I don't need "dequeue" on the end of the location replace. Any thing else would be helpful to know... Be kind!

Comment: put a `console.log(delaytimeer)` and check the value calculated. Place this below this line `var delaytimer = index * eventDuration + eventDuration;` and post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is being executed immediately because it isn't inside the delay function. Try moving it in there.

```
$('#' + value).delay(delaytimer).queue(function() {
        $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationArray[index]).dequeue();


       //Once complete redirect to the home page:
       if (index === 3) {
            $(this).delay(delaytimer + 500).queue(function() {
               window.location.replace('/').dequeue;
           });
       }
    });
```